# Azure copy activity (ingest data)

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Attempt to ingest file using azure data factory activity (copy activity) from a website. This is the link: https://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/receitas/2023. The pipeline fails during the debug.

Greetings,

When I am trying to get a file using Azure Data Factory's Copy Activity I receive the following error:

> *ErrorCode=UserErrorSourceNotSeekable,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Your HttpServer source can't support random read which is requied by current copy activity setting, please create two copy activities to work around it: the first copy activity binary copy your HttpServer source to a staging file store(like Azure Blob, Azure Data Lake, File, etc.), second copy activity copy from the staged file store to your destination with current settings.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,*'

My pipeline try to get the file from this website: https://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/receitas/2023.

I tryed again using a data set that reads binary files. Again an error. This is what the output shows:

> *ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with client error, status code 403 Forbidden, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.
> Request URL: [https://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/receitas/2023.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The](https://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/receitas/2023.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,%27%27Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The) remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=System,*'

An interesting thing is that I can download the file be clicking in the link in very error mensage given by them! (https://portaldatransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/receitas/2023).

Any help on how to solve this? I can read all the files using python requests, but I really need to work this through azure...

Many thanks